# How can I get my Label to click another Button

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I want my Label (myLabel) to select the FileUploadPassfoto Button with a OnClick Event. How can I do this?

```
<label class="myLabel" onclick="">

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPassfoto" runat="server" Visible="false"/><br />
<span>Passfoto hochladen</span>

</label>
```

Comment: Why are you using label?

Comment: Because i want to style this Label in the next step. Cause you cant really style UploadButtons.... Or is there a better way of doing that @HarshalBulsara

Comment: Can you plz update your question, what exactly you are trying to achieve, right now question is unclear

Comment: I want to Hide my original FileUpload button. I want "cover" it with a Label so i can style that label. As soon as i click the Label, i want my label to "click" my original FileUpload Button so i can upload files. Clear now? @HarshalBulsara

Comment: Max answer should work.

Comment: pointer-events to click through :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a click event through Javascript method `click()`:

```js
document.getElementById('FileUploadPassfoto').click();
```

so you get:

```js
<label class="myLabel" onclick="document.getElementById('FileUploadPassfoto').click();">
```

Comment: Do you also know how i could do this in my C# Backend code with a asp:button. I have a _Click event there, how can i implement JS init @MaximilianAst

Comment: yes exactly. I want to call it in my protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) Method with JS @MaximilianAst

Comment: If I'm not totally wrong it will call `myButton_Click` (same as if s.b. really clicks on it) if you set the `onclick` for your button right.